# SQL Update Int to Equal Int on another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-types

I want the `images.url_id` value to be the same as the `urls.url_id` value.

This is what I have come up with based off of [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30514/sql-server-use-case-expression-in-update-statement/), but it doesn't work.

```
update images
set images.url_id = urls.url_id
from images inner join urls
on images.url_id = urls.url_id
;
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Can you elaborate further than *"but it doesn't work."* - This is very vague, do you get an error message? Does it run but not with the expected results?

Comment: Sorry, yes its MySQL (Thank you marc_s), the code doesn't run (error with the syntax given), and I know its vague, but I did say _"Any help would be appreciated"_ and @Consider Me was exactly right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work, because you are trying to update `images.url_id` with value of `urls.url_id` on condition that those values are equal. You already know they are not.

If you want to set `images.url_id` equal to those from `urls.url_id` the way you want it you need to have a matching column to perform such operation for each row.

Comment: Furthermore, the UPDATE statement will UPDATE url_ids in the image table, however it will just set them to the same value they already were. OP will need to find another field to join on besides the `url_id`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you're joining based on the criteria you want rather than the criteria you have.  You'll need to join to another field that's common between the two tables or create a temporary table or CTE that gets the result you want and then join to that.

Answer (score -2):

The `CASE` expression is used to compare one expression with a set of expressions in SQL. The result of the `CASE` expression is a Boolean value, `true` or `false`. We can use various DML statements like `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` with a `CASE` statement.

Check the syntax: [SQL `CASE`](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30514/sql-server-use-case-expression-in-update-statement/).

Comment: CASE statement will facilitate what you are doing. Sorry I didn't recognize that you are looking for a code solution and you don't want to try to improve your SQL skills

Comment: I understood the reason for the CASE statement in the example given  in the linked webpage, but it doesn't apply to me as all values are NULL and not just some, hence why i left it out.

I can only apologise for people down-voting your comment, I for one haven't (as you can see by going onto my profile), but being bitter towards me because of it was unnecessary.